# How can I deploy my project into Heroku which inclues handlebar for frontend and mondoDB database and nodejs for backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, github, heroku, handlebars.js

I am new to `nodejs` and `mongoDB`. I just finished one of my project as a beginner. Now I want to deploy it to `Heroku` from `github`. How can I do that?

I am using following stack for my project.

```
Backend: MongoDB/mongoose and NodeJS/ExpressJS
Frontend: Handlebar/jQuery/AJAX
```

Any source/link from where I can refer would surely help.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use Atlas free tier.

Comment: What is that now...?